# FFmpeg : mp4 and multiple srt into mkv

Tags: bash, unix, shell, ffmpeg, zsh

I have a couple of `srt` subtitle tracks for an `mp4` video. How do I make them into `mkv` using `ffmpeg`/`avconv`?

I would like to use space efficiently. Performing conversion on **Darwin v13**. I will be grateful if anyone could help me with that. Thanks in advance.

I can use any shell that makes a sufficiently convenient environment for the operation. However, I mostly use `zsh`.

#### Example

```
/some/path
    Lecture_About_Evolution_of_Evolution.mp4
    english.srt
    native.srt
    perl.srt
    elven.srt
```

I want to generate `Lecture.mkv` out of the `mp4` file and all `*.srt` subtitle tracks. But I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the full answer that I made according to my needs.

## Code

```
#!/bin/zsh

mkv_sub_getshort() {
    sub=$1
    sub="${sub%.${sub:e}}"
    sub="$(sed 's/^.*[[:punct:]]//g' <<< "$sub")"
    echo $sub
}

mkv_maker() {
    local c=0
    for i in *srt; do
        LOCAL_SUB[((++c))]="$i"
        LOCAL_SUB_SHORT[$c]="$(mkv_sub_getshort "$i")"
    done

    local W="   "
    printf "ffmpeg -i *mp4"
    printf "$(for i in ${LOCAL_SUB[*]}; do printf "${W}-i \"$i\""; done)"
    printf "$(for i in $(seq $((${#LOCAL_SUB} + 1))); do printf "${W}-map $((i - 1))"; done)"
    printf "${W}-c copy"
    printf "$(for i in $(seq ${#LOCAL_SUB}); do ((--i)); printf "${W}-metadata:s:s:$i language=${LOCAL_SUB_SHORT[$((i + 1))]%.srt}"; done)"
    printf "${W}output.mkv"

    unset LOCAL_SUB LOCAL_SUB_SHORT
}

mkv_maker
```

This generates the command for the number of subtitle tracks in folder.

## Sample output

```
$ ls -a
.           ..          mkvmaker vid.mp4     vid_eng.srt vid_fr.srt  vid_rus.srt vid_swe.srt

$ ./mkvmaker
ffmpeg -i *mp4 -i "vid_eng.srt" -i "vid_fr.srt" -i "vid_rus.srt" -i "vid_swe.srt" -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 -c copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=fr -metadata:s:s:2 language=rus -metadata:s:s:3 language=swe output.mkv
```

## Credits

Credit goes to **[LordNeckbeard](https://superuser.com/users/110524/lordneckbeard)** for the previous answer which helped me to understand how to make this working.

Answer (score 11):

Using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle1.srt -i subtitle2.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 \
-c copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ipk output.mkv
```

- This will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c copy`) all streams, so re-encoding is avoided.
- The default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will only choose one stream per stream type, so `-map` is used to manually override that.
- I don't use `avconv`, so I don't know if any of this info will apply. Make sure you're using a recent, real version of `ffmpeg`. Development is very active and the counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" from the Libav fork is old and dead. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for various options.

Comment: Is it possible to make it independant from the number of subtitle tracks?

Comment: @theoden Can you explain in more detail? I'm not quite following what you're asking.

Comment: I mean so that all `srt`s of a mask and an `mp4` file are combined into one `mkv` file. Although the solution you provided seems to be working, it aims only 2 subtitle tracks. Is there a scheme for doing that? I added an example to make myself clear. Sorry for being slightly misunderstood.

Comment: @theoden You are looking for a complete script? I'm not a `zsh` user, but I recommend looking at globbing and arrays. [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/) is always helpful for bash.

Comment: @theoden You will have to explicitly list each SRT input as shown in the example.

Comment: So, it's like `ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i srt1 -i srt2 -i .. -i srtN -map 0 -map 1 ... -map N -c copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=lang1 ... -metadata:s:s:N-1 language=langN output.mkv`, right?

Comment: @theoden Looks good to me.