# Batch merge/mux MP4 and SRT files to MKV

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, matroska

So I've been searching around to an answer to this and have been able to find very many *similar* cases, but unable to actually find an answer to what I'm trying to do.

I took a look at these two threads in particular:

- [Batch merge/mux .srt with .mkv files](https://superuser.com/questions/1035553/batch-merge-mux-srt-with-mkv-files)
- [FFmpeg : mp4 and multiple srt into mkv](https://superuser.com/questions/958680/ffmpeg-mp4-and-multiple-srt-into-mkv)

Also Google'd around and read a bunch of man pages to no avail. (Doesn't mean the answers aren't there, I just couldn't find them!)

---

Anyway, with that preface out of the way, here's what I'm trying to do:

I have three folders (and a billion files) of this:

- Show Name - S##E## - Title.mp4
- Show Name - S##E## - Title.eng.srt

I'm trying to merge every .mp4 and .srt into just `Show Name - S##E## - Title.mkv` with the subtitles included in the file.

The problem with the first related thread that I linked is that it just turns the .mp4 into .mkv and doesn't merge the subtitles at all.

Code:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.mp4) DO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A"
```

This *creates* the .mkv file, but doesn't include the subtitles. If I try to add `"%%~dpnA.srt"` or anything after `"%%~A"`, I get a message saying: `Error: The file 'C:\Users\xnaas\Desktop\test\Show Name - S##E## - Title.srt' could not be opened for reading: open file error.` and similar. I geuss my biggest confusion here is I don't know what any of what I'm typing is doing. What is a `~` or `nA` doing?

The problem with the second link is that I don't know how to adapt it to be in batch form because I'm not sure how to do that with ffmpeg at all. I assume it's just another for loop, but I'm not all that familiar with it.

This is the only script I've used for ffmpeg (Linux now vs Windows above) before:

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 18 -c:a copy "encoded/${f%.mkv}.mkv"; done
```

I'm sure it could probably be adapted, but I'm not sure how.

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "test/${f%}.mkv"; done
```

That's the best I could come up with after a long while tinkering with it, but this obviously doesn't bring in the subtitle files and it names everything `.mp4.mkv` as well.

---

Sorry for the massive wall of crap up there. I look forward to any assistance/insight anyone can offer. Thank you!

Comment: I should add, I can use Bulk Rename Utility to remove `.eng` from every .srt file if needed. It doesn't need to be there, obviously.

Comment: Should also note: I don't care if the solution is done on Windows or in bash. I can use either. I just need...something. :)

Comment: To explain some of what's going on in the batch file, take a look at this: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Hmm...can't decide whether that created more questions than it answered or not, yet... :) Thank you for the info, though!

Comment: That definitely did it. Now I can just mess around with flags and get the rest of the details worked out. You should post your answer separately so I can mark it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain how the batch parameters that are given [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) are being applied to the script you gave.

The basic parameter in the `FOR` loop is `%%A`.  The `%%A` is modified in the following ways:

- `"%%~nA.mkv"` is removing the quotes (`~`) and using just the filename (`n`).
- `"%%~A"` is just removing any quotes (`~`)

I think your final command should end up as:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.mp4) DO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A" "%%~nA.eng.srt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, it kept the language `en`

Make sure the srt and mp.4 have the exact same name, besides the extension.

```
FOR %%A IN (*.mp4) DO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A" "%%~nA.srt" --default-language en --language 1:en
```