# Batch file to recursively mux .mp4 and .srt from different folders

Tags: video, batch-file, file-management, subtitles, matroska

There is a new trend in torrents to release TV and Movies as x265 .mp4 with .srt subs in a separate folder, following this folder structure:

```
Season1\title1.mp4
Season1\title2.mp4
Season1\title3.mp4
Season1\Subs\title1\subfile1.srt
Season1\Subs\title1\[subfile2.srt]
Season1\Subs\title1\[subfile3.srt]
Season1\Subs\title2\subfile1.srt
Season1\Subs\title2\[subfile2.srt]
Season1\Subs\title2\[subfile3.srt]
Season1\Subs\title3\subfile1.srt
Season1\Subs\title3\[subfile2.srt]
Season1\Subs\title3\[subfile3.srt]
```

**My goal is mux each .mp4 to the first .srt in its subs folder.** I can do this, one at a time, using MKVToolNix GUI, but I have been looking for a simpler/faster way to do it with a batch file (or PowerShell script). The following two solutions come close:

[Batch merge/mux MP4 and SRT files to MKV](https://superuser.com/questions/1157360/batch-merge-mux-mp4-and-srt-files-to-mkv)

[Batch merge/mux .srt with .mkv files](https://superuser.com/questions/1035553/batch-merge-mux-srt-with-mkv-files)

They only work, though, if the .mp4 and .srt are in the same folder and appropriately titled. My problem, and this is something that many others are having to deal with as well, is that under the new release standard:

- The .mp4 and .srt are in different folders.
- There may be one or multiple .srt files for every .mp4. If this is
  the case, it is safe to assume that I want the first .srt file, which
  is normally the default English subs.
- The .srt files do not follow a naming convention where the first file
  is always titled the same. In other words, the batch file would have
  to use the first .srt, no matter its name.

This 2018 script from [Sujay Phadke](https://superuser.com/users/429640/sujay-phadke), is a good start.

```
for %%f in (*.mkv) do (
    echo %%~nf
    'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe' -o "%%~nf_New.mkv" "%%~nf.mkv" --language 0:eng "%%~nf.srt"
    move /Y "%%~nf_New.mkv"  "%%~nf.mkv"
```

It works recursively as long as all the files (.mp4 and .srt) are in the same folder and properly titled. What I am looking for, though, is a batch file that does not involve renaming or moving files. It would use mkvmerge.exe to mux each .mp4 to the first .srt in its sub folder and save each new .mkv to the same folder as the .mp4.

Optionally, since this I can figure out, Mkvmerge.exe should set the .srt as **Language:English** and **force the DefaultTrack flag**.

It would work for all the .mp4 files in a season. No need for it to work from season to season unless you are feeling industrious. I would then run the batch file for each season, from the same folder as each season's .mp4 files.

Sorry for the long explanation, but this is really beyond me, and I could use your help. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off 

setlocal && cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_mkv=C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"
set "_flag_0=--default-language en --language 0:en"
set "_flag_1=--priority higher --flush-on-close --disable-track-statistics-tags -o"

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%G in (`dir /a:d /b ^|findstr Season.*[0-9] ^|find/v /i "\subs\"
   `)do if exist "%%G\*.mp4" for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in (`2^>nul where "%%~G:*.mp4"
        `)do call %:^) "%%~G" "%%~ni" "%%~i" "%_mkv%" "%_flag_0%" "%_flag_1%" "*.srt"

%:^)
if "%~1" == "" (endlocal & goto :eof)else for /f ^usebackq^delims^= %%# in (`2^>nul ^
     where "%~1\Subs\%~2:%~7"`)do "%~4" %~6 "%~dpn3.mkv" "%~3" %~5 "%%~f#" & exit /b
```

---

**1.** Save this bat at base/root (1 level above `SeasonX\` folders:

**2.** Use a `for /f` loop to get the full path of each folder`SeasonX\`

**3.** If in that folder there is an `any/more.mp4`, then this time get their path too

**4.** Save the mkv `/flags` you need and the full path of mkv executable too, and use inside the function (`:label`)

**5.** Call a function already composing the arguments to be used in it to process the mp4 when the first subtitle\file.srt is found and exit the function immediately.

---

**Obs.: 1.** The `Findstr` will filter the subfolders and allow it to run on all that match your folder name layout, below some options to check which one applies best to your scenario

```bath
dir /a:d /b | findstr /ei Season.[0-9]       |find/v /i "\subs\"
dir /a:d /b | findstr /ei Season.*[0-9]      |find/v /i "\subs\"
dir /a:d /b | findstr /ei Season[0-9][0-9]   |find/v /i "\subs\"
dir /a:d /b | findstr /ei Season.[0-9][0-9]  |find/v /i "\subs\"
dir /a:d /b | findstr /ei Season.*[0-9][0-9] |find/v /i "\subs\"
```

---

**Obs.: 2.** When calling a function in bat, it is necessary to pass the variables/string (in arguments) so that it is possible to make use of them:

```bath
::  call :label/function and passing all arguments
:: 
::  call %:^) "%%~G" "%%~ni" "%%~i" "%_mkv%" "%_flag_0%" "%_flag_1%" "* .srt"
::  call %:ˆ) "Season1" "title1" "C:\Users\Answer42\Videos\SU-2022\Season1\title1.mp4" "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" "--default-language en --language 0:en" "--priority higher --flush-on-close --disable-track-statistics-tags -o" "*.srt"
:: 
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::
::
:: %1  ==      "%%~G" == folder where .mp4 files are
:: %2  ==     "%%~ni" == the name without extension for the current mp4
:: %3  ==      "%%~i" == the full path to the current mp4 file
:: %4  ==    "%_mkv%" == the full path to the mkvmerge executable
:: %5  == "%_flag_0%" == mkv flag for process the first subtitle :: input in loop
:: %6  == "%_flag_1%" == mkv flag to process and output file
:: %7  ==     "*.srt" == subtitle extension
:: 
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::
```

---

**Obs.: 3.** Your commands inside the `for /f` loop (inside the function/label) and the result obtained in the for loop using the arguments:

```bath
for /f ... (`where "%~1\Subs\%~2:%~7"`)do...
for /f ... (`where "C:\Users\Answer42\Videos\SU-2022\Season1\Subs\title1:*.str`)do...

...)do "%~4" %~6 "%~dpn3.mkv" "%~3" %~5 "%%~f#"
...)do "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --priority higher --flush-on-close --disable-track-statistics-tags -o "C:\Users\Answer42\Videos\SU-2022\Season1\title1.mkv" "C:\Users\Answer42\Videos\SU-2022\Season1\title1.mp4" --default-language en --language 0:en "C:\Users\Answer42\Videos\SU-2022\Season1\Subs\title1\subfile1.srt"
```

---

---

> ***My goal is mux each .mp4 to the first .srt in its subs folder...***
>
> The trickiest part using this code would be to adjust the command that returns you to the correct subtitle....

- Understand that we don't know what to make the output true to the objective and we didn't even see the file, the file name, creation/change date or even its content.
- Thus, it is difficult to define what qualifies you as first (or english.str), so you would go into this part to make the adjustment if necessary replacing the current command in the function with one of the possible commands below:

```bath
%:^)
if "%~1" == "" (endlocal & goto :eof)else for /f ^usebackq^delims^= %%# in (`2^&&#62;nul ^
     where "%~1\Subs\%~2:%~7"`)do "%~4" %~6 "%~dpn3.mkv" "%~3" %~5 "%%~f#" & exit /b

:: Possible adjustments/replacement/in command:
     where "%~1\Subs\%~2:%~7"`)do...

     where "%~1\Subs\%~2:%~7"^|sort`)do...
     where "%~1\Subs\%~2:%~7"^|sort /r`)do...

     dir /b /a:-d /on /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7"`)do...
     dir /b /a:-d /o-n /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7"`)do...

     dir /b /a:-d /od /tc /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7"`)do...
     dir /b /a:-d /o-d /tc /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7"`)do...

     dir /b /a:-d /on /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7" ˆ|sort /r`)do...
     dir /b /a:-d /o-n /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7" ˆ|sort /r`)do...

     dir /b /a:-d /od /tc /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7" ^|sort`)do...
     dir /b /a:-d /o-d /tc /s "%~1\Subs\%~2\%~7" ^|sort /r`)do...
```